# npm ERR! when installing package

Tags: node.js, npm-install

when I want to install a new package, i'm getting endless error-log..

I couldn't evaluate the exact problem of it
I tried `npm cache clear` since many people suggested it but it didn't work for me.

Maybe it's a problem with permissions, I really don't know.

I also already tried reinstalling nodejs, but nothing changed, still getting an Error when trying to install highcharts with:

```
npm install highcharts --save
```

here's the npm-debug.log since it is suggested to provide it with problems

https://gist.github.com/xsoliah/20b4a8790888d5b4842769eeabe08248

thanks for your support

Comment: Could you please add what is coming on your serial?

Comment: there is nothing on serial.. i  just want to install third party packages and i get the error provided in the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm-registry url http://registry.npmjs.org/ was blocked due to my firewall settings. Adding a rule solved the problem

Unfortunatelly the error didn't contain any information related to my network-settings, so this took me some hours.

Answer (score 1):

Can you upload your package.json file?

In your npm-debug.log,
line 10489: 35 error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

It looks like your packasge.json might be at fault here.

Comment: I ran your json file on my system and installed highcharts as well, all went fine with me. Try updating npm and node versions.

Comment: i get the same error when updating npm with npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: i'm using windows 7

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to replicate the problem. When I create package.json locally and run npm install, I did not receive any error. Please ensure that you have admin privilages and npm install is not blocked.